# Using DB9 connectors for LVDS signals

Tags: connector, signal-integrity, lvds, db9

Has anyone utilized 9-pin DB9 connectors for driving and receiving LVDS signals? I wanted to use Micro-D connectors on a board I am developing but they take too long to get. Since DB9 connectors are utilized for RS-422, RS-232 that have a differential 100 Ohm characteristic impedance, I figured it would work with LVDS as well.

I am driving and receiving LVDS signals up to 100 Mbps. Distance 20-40 inches

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As the *name itself suggests, the LVDS is **low voltage** signalling compared to RS422 or RS485.. so has a limitation in terms of range compared to the latter two. The voltage swing is about 350 mV.

100 Mbps with a two DB9 connectors in the line with a distance one meter cable will have matching impedance issues. [DB9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Speed) on the other hand, in general, are not meant to be used for high speed. There are special DB9 connectors as well, which supports high data rate (in Gbps). I have used both DB15 connectors and also Berg stick connectors for a range of unto 10 inch with MLVDS without any issues.
With respect to speed too, LVDS is better due to low voltage swing compared to the other standards so can achieve higher datarate.

**Update 2:** the 100 Mbps signalling over 1 meter cable *may need* matching to avoid reflections (depending on the rise time of the signal)

Comment: not sure the differential part of LVDS would be happy with DB-9, from length and impedance matching standpoint